# Issue with Javascript (call asynchronously)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying change text before I get feeds.
But the text changes after I got the feeds.
The question/answer it's only for Google Chrome (because it's an extension)
Sorry for my poor english ;-)

```
$("h1").click(function(){

    $(this).text("Loading..."); // this happen after fids();
    fids(); // function to get feeds

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to change `fids` to work asynchronously, but if you can't do that, you can run `fids` in a timeout:

```
$("h1").click(function(){
    $(this).text("Loading...");
    setTimeout(fids, 0);
});
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/v5L9M/) on JSFiddle.**

The reason it doesn't work the way you had it is that in all common browsers, JavaScript runs on the UI thread. If you change the text and then call a blocking function, the browser waits for the JavaScript to finish running before it updates the UI. Using `setTimeout` makes it run on the next event loop, after the browser has had time to redraw the text.

Comment: Right .. but why does it act like so?

Comment: It works. Thank you. But I have the same problem if after this function I want write $("h2").show(); for exemple. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Michäel: I'm not sure I understand your problem. I've got an example of something with `$("h2").show();` working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cW99S/).

Comment: For exemple. After setTimeout(fids, 0); I write $(this).hide(); $("h2").show(); [this happen before I got the feeds too]

Comment: h2 is hidden from css (display:none). Only when I got the feeds I want h2 being visible

Comment: In your example, you write $("h1").text("Loaded."); $("h2").show(); in a fids function that contains $.ajax (I don't have these piece of code in fids function)

Comment: @Michäel: Try something like this then: `var self = this; setTimeout(function() { fids(); $(self).hide(); $("h2").show(); }, 0);`

Comment: You're the boss. Thank you very much. Now, I'm reading a jquery book. I wait to learn a lot :-P I tell you again, thank you for your wasted time. Greetings from Europe!

Comment: You speaks about to change fids to work asynchronously. I'll try it. Thank you again.